# Cannot find event for update new mail in Outlook addin

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I'm working on addin for outlook and I'm need to apply some start text formatting for each new mail.
My problem is in that I cannot find appropriate place to call my code.
I need some event/callback where ActiveInspector.CurrentItem already exists.

*MailItem.NewMail*, if I understand correct, means saving item, but not opening new empty mail in inspector.

Next I found *MailItem.Open* event and it can be what I am looking for. But this is event of item instance, so first I need cutch new item when it creating and add handler to it's Open event, but where can I do it?

I'm trying add handler to *Application.Inspectors.NewInspector* and from that handler add another on to MailItem.Open, but NewInspector calls only once when first inspector creating. I'm know that each closed inspector not removing but just hiding and new inspector will be create only if reserve of hiden inspector ends. But NewInspector calls only once and it realy strange for me.

**C#, Outlook 2007, not using VSTO.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.Inspectors.NewInspector will fire just fine if you will keep Inspectors object that raises the events in a global (class) variable to make sure it does not get garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Now NewInspector raised every time I open new window.
But as for me it's strange. Why Outlook doesn't keeps value of the Inspectors variable?

Comment: because your code releases it - when you call "Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += ...", the compiler creates a temporary variable to hold the value of Application.Inspectors. As soon as the Garbage Collector runs and releases it, no events are raised by that object

Comment: I'm not supposed that value Application.Inspectors was created dynamically. I always used to return a dynamically created objects methods kind GetSomething. Good habit played a cruel joke with me :)